# Ansible - append to list which is a value of a dictionary

Tags: ansible

I have the following dictionary in Ansible:

```
{ "L0_Group_0": [ "3600a098038304437415d4b6a59684346" ], "L0_Group_1": [ "3600a098038304437415d4b6a59684346" ] }
```

Now, i want to be able to append to the list of values according the key.
For example, i want to add value '123' to key 'L0_Group_0':

```
{ "L0_Group_0": [ "3600a098038304437415d4b6a59684346","123" ], "L0_Group_1": [ "3600a098038304437415d4b6a59684346" ] }
```

What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The below is working. The `test` inside `[ ]` is static.

```
---
- hosts: localhost 
  vars:
    test: { "L0_Group_0": [ "3600a098038304437415d4b6a59684346" ], "L0_Group_1": [ "3600a098038304437415d4b6a59684346" ] }
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.value + [ 'test'] }}"
      with_items:
        - "{{ test | dict2items }}"
```

**Output:**

```
jenkins@b465f3c8330f:/root/SO/ansible$ ansible-playbook tmp.yml
[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'


PLAY [localhost] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'key': 'L0_Group_0', 'value': ['3600a098038304437415d4b6a59684346']}) => {
    "msg": [
        "3600a098038304437415d4b6a59684346",
        "test"
    ]
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'key': 'L0_Group_1', 'value': ['3600a098038304437415d4b6a59684346']}) => {
    "msg": [
        "3600a098038304437415d4b6a59684346",
        "test"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: If this resolves your issue....kindly consider accepting this as an answer and do upvote it :)